# Batch file If statement - syntax error?

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error

I'm making a small batch file to look up the French perfect tense verbs that take etre, which comes from a text file. 
The whole file works, except this segment:

```
echo Type Q and hit enter to quit, enter any other key to try another verb.
set /p option=Enter Option:
IF %option%==Q(
  goto :quit
) else (
  goto :1
)
```

Typing Q and entering it works fine, but anything else comes up with the error 'incorrect syntax'. I can't see what's incorrect here, can anyone help?

Comment: You need a space between the 'Q' and the '(' in your IF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a space.
`IF %option%==Q (`

Comment: It seems to be working now, thanks! I wasn't aware the syntax had to be that complete, as with other languages.